# Mixture problem might be missing something

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

A winemaker wants to mix a $10\%$ alcohol wine with $20 \text{ kg}$ of a $55\%$ wine to make a $35\%$ wine cooler. How much of the $10\%$ should be used?

I started with $.1x+.55y=.35$ then I'm not sure how to proceed. They should tell me the $10\%$ amount or $35%$ amount.

The same thing seems to be happening with the following.
How much pure alcohol must be added to $40 \text{ oz}$ of a $25\%$ alcohol solution to produce a mixture that is $40\%$ alcohol?

I started with $x+.25y=.4$ , so shouldn't they tell me the total amount or pure amount?

Either I forgot it over the summer, or the homework is missing a part.

Comment: They did tell you the 35% amount -- 20kg.

Comment: @ian coley It says nothing of 10 plus 20 of 55 to make 35 of some amount.

Comment: Try setting up your equations differently so that you are calculating a percent rather than an amount.

Comment: How would I do that? @IanColey

Comment: If you add $x$ kg of $10%$% wine to the $20$ kg of $55%$% wine, how much wine do you have altogether (in kg)? And how much alcohol in kg?

Comment: Exactly what I don't know. @MarkBennet

Comment: @Player72 Can you see why you have $x+20$ of wine and $0.1x+11$ of alcohol. Convert this into a linear equation for $x$.

Comment: I see x+20 but where was the .1x + 11 from? @MarkBennet

Comment: @Player72 $10$% of the new wine plus $0.55\times 20=11$ kg of the original wine.

Comment: Therefore the equation is x-y = 20 and .1x -y = 11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mixture problems make more sense if you organize the information into a chart:

$wt\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \  \%\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  pure EtOH$
$20\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \     0.55\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   20(.55)  $
$x\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \     0.1\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \       .1x$
$20+x\ \ \    0.35 \ \ \ \    (20+x)(.35)$

The amount of ethanol in the mixture is the sum of its two constituents:
$20(.55)+.1x=(20+x)(.35)$

Comment: I'm not sure if there's ethanol in this problem... But ok.

Comment: Ok it works. Should I do the same for the second problem? @reluctantmathematician

Comment: By the way, it's algebra II so don't overthink it please. @reluctantmathematician

Comment: Works thanks a lot.

Comment: Ethanol is pure alcohol. I suppose that I should not presume to use organic chemistry notation... yes, this type of chart will work for almost every mixture problem. @Player72

Comment: haha, sorry mate, im only a 9th grader (or year nine) and i didn't learn the notation yet. @reluctantmathematician